# UITableView is not displayed in programmatic UIKit ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I'm using UIKit programmatically. I've got a `UITableView` working fine in another view controller, and I've largely copied the code I used there to this VC, and yet I get no errors and the `UITableView` is not displayed. I checked the Debug View Hierarchy and it isn't present there either. I'm not sure if this is related, but upon launching the Debug View Hierarchy the following message is displayed repeatedly in the debug window:
`[API] Failed to get renderer info (client=0x82b3d507) [0x5 (os/kern) failure]`. My `print` statement inside `numberOfRowsInSection` does fire, but my `print` statement in `cellForRowAt` does not. `WorkoutTemplate` and its child structs are simple data structures with no logic. I have a static property on WorkoutTemplate that is used for dummy data when laying out the UI.

```
class CreateWorkoutVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    var exerciseListing: UITableView!
    
    var workoutTemplate: WorkoutTemplate!
    
    init(workoutTemplate: WorkoutTemplate) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        
        self.workoutTemplate = workoutTemplate

        configure()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
    }
    
    private func configure() {
        let padding: CGFloat = 20

        exerciseListing = UITableView(frame: view.frame)

        view.addSubview(exerciseListing)
        
        exerciseListing.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "exercise")
        exerciseListing.rowHeight = 50
        exerciseListing.dataSource = self
        exerciseListing.delegate = self
        exerciseListing.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            exerciseListing.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: padding),
            exerciseListing.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
            exerciseListing.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding)
        ])
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print("In numberOfRowsInSection: \(workoutTemplate.exerciseSets.count)")
        return workoutTemplate.exerciseSets.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "exercise", for: indexPath)
        
        let cellLabel = getCellLabel(withText: workoutTemplate.exerciseSets[indexPath.row].exercise.exerciseName)
        print(workoutTemplate.exerciseSets[indexPath.row].exercise.exerciseName)
        cell.addSubview(cellLabel)
        
        let padding: CGFloat = 8
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cellLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.centerYAnchor),
            cellLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor, constant: padding),
            cellLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.trailingAnchor, constant: -padding),
            cellLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.heightAnchor)
        ])
        
        cell.backgroundColor = .secondarySystemBackground
        
        return cell
    }
    
    func getCellLabel(withText labelText: String) -> UILabel {
        let cellLabel = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        cellLabel.text = labelText
        cellLabel.textColor = .label
        cellLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        cellLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.90
        cellLabel.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
        cellLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        cellLabel.textAlignment = .left
        cellLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16, weight: .bold)
        
        return cellLabel
    }
}
```

Data Structures:

```
struct WorkoutTemplate {
    let workoutName: String
    var exerciseSets: [ExerciseSet]
    
    mutating func addExerciseSet(exerciseSet: ExerciseSet) {
        exerciseSets.append(exerciseSet)
    }
    
    static let exampleWorkouts = [WorkoutTemplate(workoutName: "Upper Body 1", exerciseSets: [ExerciseSet(exercise: Exercise(exerciseId: UUID(), exerciseName: "Bench Press"), sets: 3, targetReps: 8, targetRPE: 8, restPeriod: 2), ExerciseSet(exercise: Exercise(exerciseId: UUID(), exerciseName: "T-Bar Row"), sets: 3, targetReps: 8, targetRPE: 8, restPeriod: 3)]), WorkoutTemplate(workoutName: "Lower Body 1", exerciseSets: [ExerciseSet(exercise: Exercise(exerciseId: UUID(), exerciseName: "Hack Squats"), sets: 3, targetReps: 8, targetRPE: 8, restPeriod: 2), ExerciseSet(exercise: Exercise(exerciseId: UUID(), exerciseName: "Leg Ext"), sets: 3, targetReps: 8, targetRPE: 8, restPeriod: 3)])]
}

struct ExerciseSet {
    let exercise: Exercise
    let sets: Int
    let targetReps: Int
    let targetRPE: Int
    let restPeriod: Int
}

struct Exercise {
    let exerciseId: UUID
    let exerciseName: String
}
```

Comment: Show how you create an instance of `CreateWorkoutVC`. And why not use a `UITableViewController`? Why extend `UIViewController` with a table view?

Comment: This isn’t your immediate problem but you are adding another label and its constraints in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. That method will be called for existing cells when they are reused on scrolling. You should add the label and the constraints in the cell class so they only happen once.

Comment: @HangarRash There's more than a UITableView managed by the view controller. There's also UILabels, UITextFields and UIButtons. I've removed them here both for clarity and as part of my debug process to see if their removal would cause the TableView to display. Unfortunately their removal has no effect on the TableView.

Comment: No bottom anchor/constraint? Could you override `layoutSubView` and print the frame of your tabeView there? `cellForRowAt` won't be called if there is no cell to show

Comment: @Rob The graphical representation that looks like a rotatable wireframe.

Comment: You should also be adding the label to the cell’s `contentView` and using constraints with the content view rather than adding the label directly to the cell.

Comment: @Rob Thanks! You pointed me in the right direction. In the view hierarchy in the left panel there was a purple warning icon indicating that the TableView height was ambiguous. After setting a heightAnchor constraint the TableView showed up fine.

Comment: Unrelated, I would move the cell initialization into a cell subclass, so you do that only once. E.g. https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/54833388ee0fa5a0107579fd4711419f.

Comment: @Rob Agreed and I just did so. Using the vanilla `UITableViewCell` without subclassing doesn't seem very practical. But I'm new to this, so perhaps there's a use case I'm unaware of.

Comment: The vanilla `UITableViewCell` is extremely convenient, at it already has a label (and, optionally, a subtitle label, and an image view) for free. It’s great for quick, one-off sort of things where you have not yet configured your own cell. But as soon as we get into the business of configuring custom cells, then we create our own subclasses for that…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> I checked the Debug View Hierarchy and it isn't present there either.

You checked in the graphical representation? Or in the hierarchy in the panel on the left? I ask because you do not appear to ever set the bottom constraint, so its height could be anything (even zero). And that would cause `numberOfRowsInSection` to be called, but `cellForRowAt` not to be called.

Bottom line, the table view was zero height, you wouldn’t see it in that wireframe (or it would appear to be a horizontal line). That’s why I advise navigating through the view hierarchy in the panel on the left, to find the tableview. The wireframe is great at debugging placement of views that you can see, but zero height views are harder to analyzer in there.